# Bash(awk) - Getting averages from rows of numbers

Tags: awk

I am to do a bash program where it reads a name, stores it, then reads scores to find if an avg is above 60. If it is, print out their name. So the file looks like this

```
tim 50 60 70
roy 90 80 90
```

The program should only print out "roy" because he was the only one with a passing grade. This is what I got. I am just unsure about where to put things like ;,{},and() so I'm sure my code is hideous:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{name=$i}
{avg=0}
{
  count=0;
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
    avg+=$i
  count++;
}
avg=avg/count {
  if(avg >= 60) 
    printf("%s ", name)
}'
```

Suprisingly, it compiles with no errors, however nothing prints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly there:

```
awk '{
  name=$1
  tot=0
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
    tot+=$i
  if(tot/(NF-1)>60)
    print name
  }' yourfile
```

Comment: This works! two questions though, why do you have to put $NF, and NF-1? What are these two statements doing?

Comment: The $NF was an error - from having written too much Perl this week. I have corrected it.

Comment: There is no need for your 'count' variable since awk kindly tells us how many fields there are in 'NF' and we simply subtract one to allow for the name being one of the fields.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It would still be a good idea to keep `count`, but define it explicitly as `count=NF-1` at the top of the block.  As an example I've included `name=$1`.  It's a good way to make code self-documenting.